# Android emulator cache size

Tags: android

I was wondering how I can specify the size of cache in Android emulator?
Also, how do I know the cache size of my emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse you can manipulate it through the AVD Manager by editing your Emulator definition and setting the values for Cache Partition Support and Cache Partition Size. The default cache size is 66mb.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

At the time of creation of emulator, we can specify the cache size you can give the size of cache according to your application requirement.